# Casting custom class to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've searched everywhere but to no avail:

Can you cast a custom class to NSDictionary?

Use case:

I have a `Todo` class containing some properties and I want to save it to Firebase with `taskRef.setValue(task as? NSDictionary)` however I don't even know if this is possible.

Here's my Todo class:

```
class Todo : NSObject{
    var name: String
    var desc: String
    var date: Double
    var location: [Double]?
    var snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot?

    init(name: String, desc: String? = nil, date: Double, location: [Double]? = nil){
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc!
        self.date = date
        self.snapshot = nil
        self.location = location
    }

    convenience init(name: String, desc: String? = nil, date: NSDate, location: CLLocationCoordinate2D? = nil){
        var serLoc: [Double]? = nil
        if let location = location {
            serLoc = [location.latitude, location.longitude]
        }
        self.init(name: name, desc: desc, date: date.timeIntervalSince1970 as Double, location: serLoc)
    }

    convenience init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot){
        let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        let location = dict["location"] as? [Double]
        self.init(name: dict["name"] as! String, desc: dict["desc"] as? String, date: dict["date"] as! Double, location: location)
        self.snapshot = snapshot
    }

    convenience override init(){
        self.init(name: "", desc: "", date: NSDate())
    }

}
```

Comment: Create a method `toDictionary()` (for instance) that transform the `Todo` object into a `NSDictionary` according to its values.

Comment: Do I have to manually set the `key -> value` for each property? Isn't there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot "cast" a custom class to `NSDictionary`. (Or a Swift dictionary either.) Casting is telling the compiler "Don't worry, this object is really a dictionary. Trust me." Casting is not converting. If you try to CAST a custom object that is not a dictionary to a dictionary, it won't **BE** a dictionary.

You need to convert your object to a dictionary, not cast it. As Larme suggests in his comment, add a `toDictionary` method to your class that returns a dictionary that encodes the properties of your object into key/value pairs in the dictionary.

Then create a custom init method that takes a dictionary as a parameter.

I seem to remember reading that there are Swift methods that let you interrogate the properties of an object and get their names. You could write your toDictionary code to use that. If I remember correctly they use `Mirror` and `.children`. If you don't want to write custom code to convert your object's properties, take a look at Mirror.

Answer (score 1):

If the dictionary is not restricted to property list types add a property

```
var dictionaryRepresentation : [String:AnyObject] {
    var result : [String:AnyObject] = ["name" : name,  "desc" : desc,  "date" : date]
    result["snapshot"] = snapshot 
    result["location"] = location
    return result
}
```

.

Comment: Can you easily cast `Dictionary` to `NSDictionary`?

Comment: Yes you can (unlike `NSMutableDictionary`)

Comment: How? just normal cast? `as? NSDictionary`?

Comment: *bridge cast* -> `as NSDictionary` (without exclamation nor question mark) but in most cases Swift `Dictionary` is bridged implicitly.

Comment: One last question. I went with your advice and implemented this property. It throws an error when trying to insert location (prob. because of `nil`?) how do I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. A dictionary creation with a literal does not support `nil` values. I updated the answer.

Comment: I've figured it out. I've returned an instance of NSDictionary instead. Thanks a bunch!